# Magento 2.3 modify link plugin in WYSIWYG TinyMCE4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, wysiwyg, tinymce

In Magento 2.3 i'm trying to modify the link plugin to add a field to select a class for the link.

I had something like this in Magento1 :

[image]*

I wish to have the same here in Magento 2.3 :

[image]

I tried to follow the TinyMCE4 doc https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/plugins/link/ with the "link_class_list" option with no success.

Following the M2.3 doc did not help me, https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-wysiwyg.html

What is the best way to add option to an existing plugin in magento 2.3 ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a way to solve my issue.
I created a plugin on Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config

```
<type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config">
    <plugin name="add_link_class_selector_to_wysiwyg" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\WysiwygConfigPlugin" sortOrder="10" />
</type>
```

And my plugin file

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class WysiwygConfigPlugin {
    public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $subject, \Magento\Framework\DataObject $config)
    {
        $config->addData(
            [
                'settings' => [
                    'link_class_list' => [
                        ['title'=> 'None', 'value'=> '0'],
                        ['title'=> 'test', 'value'=> '1']
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        );
        return $config;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure this is the best way but it works.